# Finding sum of many sub matrices in a big matrix?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matrix

For a 2D matrix A, we want to find the sum of the submatrix from `(x1,y1)` to `(x2, y2)` coordinates.

I came across this [explanation](https://prismoskills.appspot.com/lessons/Arrays/Submatrix_Sum.jsp) of finding the submatrix sums, and I can follow the logic of the solution until the last part where they perform the following computation:

`sum[x2][y2] + sum[x1][y1] - sum[x1][y2] - sum[x2][y1]`

The idea is that they compute a matrix where each point represent the sum of the matrix, with all of which with reference to the original x1,y1 being (0,0). Then using some geometry method, they get the sums for a certain sub array. What I don't get is the geometry part. How does it come into play? I will draw the array for the sake of completeness.

Assume we have A as such:

```
1  2  3


4  5  6


7  8  9
```

For example, assume after finding the matrix sums we have the following:

```
1  3  6


5  12  21


12  27  45
```

Assume that I want to find the sum of the sub array starting from (1,1) to (2,2) where (0,0) is the origin at the sum 10. Then according to the formula, we have the sum

`A[2][2] + A[1][1] - A[1][2] - A[2][1]`

which gives 12 + 45 - 27 - 21 = 9.

Which isn't really the correct answer, 28?

Is there something wrong with this answer?

Comment: It is actually `sum[x2][y2] + sum[x1-1][y1-1] - sum[x1-1][y2] - sum[x2][y1-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calculating the sums you mentioned, `sum[x][y]` will represent the sum of the rectangle from `(0,0) to (x,y)`.

Now we want to calculate the sum of the subarray from `(x1,y1) to (x2,y2)`. We start with `sum[x2][y2]`. we need to subtract `sum[x1-1][y2]` and `sum[x2][y1-1]` since they don't belong to the required rectangle. However, notice that the red rectangle was subtracted twice, so we add `sum[x1-1][y1-1]`

[image]